# Ubuntu 18.04 USB boots to GRUB

Tags: boot, 18.04, grub2, usb

I'm trying to boot to Ubuntu 18.04 I followed this [tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview) to download the Ubuntu 18.04 .iso file and configure the USB using Rufus. When I boot from the drive it just loads into the grub terminal...

I already have a dual boot Ubuntu/Windows setup on my machine, I am trying to boot into a test version of Ubuntu so that I can resize the partitions on my main drive.

How do I get past this GRUB terminal so that can boot and load into Ubuntu?

Thanks,
John

Comment: Did you create a space for the new installation and which Ubuntu are "loading" into here?

Comment: I'm not trying to install Ubuntu again, I just want to boot off of the USB into a trail mode.